# ChartJS 2 lines each with different fill gradients

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, chart.js

I have ChartJS version 2.6 in an Ionic 3/Angular 4 app. In my line chart config I have 2 datasets. I have been stuck trying to get both the 2 lines to have their own fill gradients.

I need something like this:

[image: Example]

But so far I have only managed something like this:

[image: My Attempt]

No matter what I try, my 1st dataset chart always over-powers the 2nd one. Like it hides the 2nd one.

Here is the chart config I am trying:

```
let chart = this.lineCanvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d'),
    gradientSys = chart.createLinearGradient(0, 200, 0, 0);

    gradientSys.addColorStop(0.4, 'rgba(49, 218, 11, 1)');
    gradientSys.addColorStop(0.7, 'rgba(218, 129, 11, 1)');
    gradientSys.addColorStop(1.0, 'rgba(218, 11, 11, 1)');

    let gradientDia = chart.createLinearGradient(0, 120, 0, 0);

    gradientDia.addColorStop(0.4, 'rgba(49, 218, 11, 1)');
    gradientDia.addColorStop(0.6, 'rgba(218, 129, 11, 1)');
    gradientDia.addColorStop(1.0, 'rgba(218, 11, 11, 1)');

    this.chartConfig = {
        type: 'line',

        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        min: 0,
                        callback: function (value, index, values) {
                            if (Math.floor(value) === value) {
                                return value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        },

        data: {
            labels: [],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Systolic',
                    fill: true,
                    lineTension: 0.1,
                    backgroundColor: gradientSys,
                    borderColor: "rgba(115, 115, 115, 1)",
                    borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                    borderDash: [],
                    borderDashOffset: 1.0,
                    borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                    pointBorderColor: "rgba(115, 115, 115, 1)",
                    pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                    pointBorderWidth: 1,
                    pointHoverRadius: 5,
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(115, 115, 115, 1)",
                    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(115, 115, 115, 1)",
                    pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                    pointRadius: 3,
                    pointHitRadius: 10,
                    spanGaps: false,
                    data: []
                },
                {
                    label: 'Diastolic',
                    fill: true,
                    lineTension: 0.1,
                    backgroundColor: gradientDia,
                    borderColor: 'rgba(115, 115, 115, 1)',
                    borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                    borderDash: [],
                    borderDashOffset: 1.0,
                    borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                    pointBorderColor: 'rgba(115, 115, 115, 1)',
                    pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                    pointBorderWidth: 1,
                    pointHoverRadius: 5,
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(115, 115, 115, 1)',
                    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(115, 115, 115, 1)',
                    pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                    pointRadius: 3,
                    pointHitRadius: 10,
                    spanGaps: false,
                    data: []
                }
            ]
        }
    };
```

The data [] values are empty there as I set them later on after I got them from the database. I have tried to set the fill value for the 1st dataset as '-1', but that breaks. Please point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Have you tried swapping the two array entries in the `dataset`? It is not clear whether the second picture you're showing is Systolic or Diastolic, but if it is the latter, I would guess it is because entry 1 will plot over entry 0. If Systolic will always be lower, make that the last entry, so it is plotted last?

Comment: The other thing you could think about is creating two chart objects that sit on top of each other, so if flipping the data order does not help, create two charts so the chart z-indexes can be flipped instead.

Comment: Hello @halfer thank you so much! Systolic is the to one yes, when swapping around the datasets it worked!

Comment: You're welcome, please that worked - it was a guess! I have written it up below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We discussed two possible solutions in the comments.

The option that worked was simply to reverse the rendering order: simply swapping `datasets[0]` with `datasets[1]` (and vice versa) did the trick. I would expect the JavaScript library here plots one graph over the other, so if one graph is always the larger, it needs to be plotted first.

If this had not worked, another option that could have been considered is to create two separate graph objects, and map them to two DOM elements that overlay each other exactly. If the graph objects are transparent in each case (i.e. the background has no fill colour) then this may have worked.